# Can we source job postings from stackoverflow.com/jobs?

Tags: support, jobs

Is there an API for [stackoverflow.com/jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)?

What are the terms and Conditions of using data from stackoverflow.com/jobs and its API?

Comment: The site you're asking this on - Stack Apps - is community-run. The team that owns the sites _might_ be looking, but I wouldn't want to bank on it - I suggest you ask them directly instead, since they're the ones who can give you authority (or not) to do this. [Here's the contact form](/contact).